# htaccess with wildcard SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl-certificate

We have a Wildcard SSL Certificate that is supposed to work on any subdomain of a given domain.

So in this server we have this file structure:

**/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainx
/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainy**
etc...

Now, the Certificate is installed, but when you visit any subdomain over https (example: hxxps://subdomainx.domain.com ) it points to

**/home/DOMAIN/public_html/index.php**

We need that when you visit a subdomain via https
hxxps://subdomainx.domain.com

That it points to the the same directory that it's http equivalent: **/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainx**

Our provider tells us that this is not possible, that the current behaviour is correct, and that to achieve this we need to do it with htaccess.

I've tried a few things, incluiding this solution, that seems to be what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365612/advice-on-configuring-htaccess-file-to-redirect-http-subdomain-to-https-equival

But can't get it to work.

Any tips? Thanks.

**Added:**
The server is Apache.

Comment: The wildcard SSL in this scenario isn't that important, other than to prevent the browser from complaining.  The question you're really asking is how to redirect requests to the proper directory.  You'll have to tell us what web server you're using and show us the relevant part of your configuration.

Comment: Server is Apache. Right now the .htaccess is empty. I'll try to reproduce what we tried and add it later.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, the "relevant parts" cjc is talking about are the vhosts with the `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` and `DocumentRoot` directives in them.  All of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the ssl.subdomain.domain.com.conf properly configured in your vhost folder.

This file should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com subdomain.domain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html/subdomain
BytesLog domlogs/domain-bytes_log
ServerName www.domain.com
CustomLog domlogs/domain.com-access_log combined
#ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/domain/public_html/cgi-bin/

User domain
Group domain

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/domain/etc/

SSLEnable
SSLCertificateFile /opt/apache/conf/ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/apache/conf/ssl.key/domain.com.key
SSLLogFile /var/log/ssl/domain.com_log
UserDir public_html
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown


. 
.
.

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that you're in need of a `NameVirtualHost *:443` (or however your vhosts are defined).

Another option would be to define a `VirtualDocumentRoot`, if your vhost configs are all identical except for the docroot.

`.htaccess` files are definitely not required for ***anything*** that you can do with Apache - with the exception of "use htaccess files".